# Spring Security Access Denied Handler is called when the HttpServletResponse is already committed

Tags: spring-security

I have an HTTP API, protected with Spring Security and JWT.
I get a 401 when I'm trying to access a protected resource.
I get the resource if I'm authenticated (JWT is valid) and I have the correct role. The resource is protected with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")`.

The issue I have is that when I don't have the correct role I'd like to return a 403 (in the following code it is a 401 for the sake of testing). 
But right know I get a 500 because of the AccessDeniedException which is thrown when the role is incorrect.
The weird thing is that it goes to my JwtAccessDeniedHandler custom code but the response is already committed (isCommitted() == true) so whenever I try to set the status etc it does nothing.
Do you have any ideas about what could be misconfigured or missing?

Config:

```
@Slf4j
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(
                        jwtAuthenticationFilter(joseHelper(jsonWebKey())),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .accessDeniedHandler(new JwtAccessDeniedHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(JoseHelper joseHelper) {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter(joseHelper);
    }

    @Bean
    public JoseHelper joseHelper(PublicJsonWebKey key) {
        return new JoseHelper(key);
    }

    @Bean
    public PublicJsonWebKey jsonWebKey() throws IOException, JoseException {
        return RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);
    }

    private void sendUnauthorized(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        ApiError apiError = ApiError.builder()
                .code(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.name())
                .message(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase())
                .httpStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .build();
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(apiError));
    }

    private class JwtAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
            log.info("accessDeniedHandler", e);
            sendUnauthorized(httpServletResponse);
        }
    }

    private class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                             HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                             AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
            sendUnauthorized(httpServletResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Filter:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer ";

    private JoseHelper joseHelper;

    @Autowired
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JoseHelper joseHelper) {
        this.joseHelper = joseHelper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(BEARER)) {
            log.error("JWT token is not valid");
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            return;
        }

        final String encryptedToken = header.substring(BEARER.length());

        try {
            final String decryptedJwt = joseHelper.decryptJwt(encryptedToken);
            final String verifiedJwt = joseHelper.verifyJwt(decryptedJwt);
            final JwtClaims jwtClaims = joseHelper.parse(verifiedJwt);

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtClaims.getStringListClaimValue("userRoles")
                    .stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

            JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwtClaims, null, authorities);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(jwtAuthenticationToken);
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        } catch (JoseException | InvalidJwtException | MalformedClaimException e) {
            log.error("JWT token is not valid", e);
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because I use Jersey apparently. I didn't really had time to investigate the why right now.
Once I registered an exception mapper in my JerseyConfig I was able to capture and handle the AccessDeniedException correctly.
And from that point the access denied handler is not called anymore and becomes useless.
A bit weird, but there is probably a good reason.

Comment: Just in case someone gets here and want to know the root cause, it's because jersey is wrapping it up on a ServletException. More accurate answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21638070/1839558